# Override Google Maps Directions Zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, fitbounds

I am trying to over-ride Google Maps driving directions zoom.  Yes, I have seen another question here on stackoverflow that is identical; however, that solution is not working for me.

Here is where I call a new DirectionsRenderer, and I define preserveViewport: true;

```
var dr = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  map: map,
  draggable: false,
  preserveViewport: true
});
```

Here is where I call the routing service, and I define setOptions preserveviewport:true;

```
 ds.route({
  origin: from,
  destination: to,
  travelMode: mode
}, function(result, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      fitBounds = true;
      dr.setOptions({ preserveViewport: true });
      dr.setDirections(result);
    }
});
```

However, this is not overriding the zoom functionality of directions service.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.  Instead of calling map.fitbounds, I used map.setZoom.  Fitbounds is to fit all the points on the screen, at the maximum zoom level.  setZoom allows you to set your own zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced fitBounds with map.setZoom() , if i set preserveViewport as true, then my map is not visible.